# Expo app stucked with white screen and text : 'Open App.js to start working on your app' when trying to run in no-dev mode

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I run my app using `npx expo start`, my app runs fine on my android phone. But, when I am trying to run using `npx expo start --no-dev`, the app is only showing a white screen with the text 'Open App.js to start working on your app'.

I have tried deleting and reinstalling the package.json file and node modules, but still the problem persists.

The GitHub link to the repository of this project is [repo](https://github.com/aashish-pandey/BusBookingApp/tree/main/MobileFrontEnd).

The screenshot of view that I am getting while running in `--no-dev` mode is [ScreenshotImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lNhr.jpg)

UPDATE: When I am trying to reload my app form CLI, I am getting this warning: `warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.`
So, I guess, my phone is not connecting to the app when the app is launched in `--no-dev mode`.

Comment: Can you show us the code, examples or other data so we can see what is wrong with it, please? Thank you!

Comment: This is a link to the Github repository of this project. [GitHub](https://github.com/aashish-pandey/BusBookingApp/tree/main/MobileFrontEnd)

Comment: I have tried your repo but i ran into an issue saying i had no right to GraphQL.

Comment: I have not used GraphQL.

Comment: have you tried clearing cache and running again?

Comment: yes, if I use `expo start -c --no-dev`, then the app is connected but it crashes (the app is automatically closed on starting).

Comment: Sorry, GraphQL was a mistake from eas on my side. I now have the same `reload` issue with both commands.

Comment: I hope you are able to run the app with `npx expo start` or are you facing issue in this also?